# Adding outline border to SVG image

Tags: c#, winforms, svg

I am drawing [this SVG graphic Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chess_Pieces_Sprite.svg) on WinForms using [the SVG.NET library](https://github.com/svg-net/SVG).

[image]

The problem is that the line is not visible when the background is black, like the first image below. I want to add an outline border, but not like the second image below. I want to add a white outline border like the third image below. Is that possible?

[image] . [image] . [image]

Comment: you can draw inside the group a rectangle with the size (width height) and position (x y) of the bounding box of the group. The rect may have fill="none" and the stroke you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS filter drop-shadows are applied to SVG elements:

[image]

```html
<style>
 svg{
  width:180px;
  filter:drop-shadow(5px 5px 0px darkgreen) drop-shadow(-5px -5px 0px darkgreen); 
 }
</style>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 44 44" style="stroke-width:1.5; stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round">
        <path d="M 22.5,11.63 L 22.5,6M 20,8 L 25,8M 22.5,25 C 22.5,25 27,17.5 25.5,14.5 C 25.5,14.5 24.5,12 22.5,12 C 20.5,12 19.5,14.5 19.5,14.5 C 18,17.5 22.5,25 22.5,25" style="fill:#ffffff; stroke:#000000; stroke-linecap:butt; stroke-linejoin:miter;"/>
        <path d="M 11.5,37 C 17,40.5 27,40.5 32.5,37 L 32.5,30 C 32.5,30 41.5,25.5 38.5,19.5 C 34.5,13 25,16 22.5,23.5 L 22.5,27 L 22.5,23.5 C 19,16 9.5,13 6.5,19.5 C 3.5,25.5 11.5,29.5 11.5,29.5 L 11.5,37z " style="fill:#ffffff; stroke:#000000;"/>
        <path d="M 11.5,30 C 17,27 27,27 32.5,30M 11.5,33.5 C 17,30.5 27,30.5 32.5,33.5" style="fill:none; stroke:#000000;"/>
        <path d="M 11.5,37 C 17,34 27,34 32.5,37" style="fill:none; stroke:#000000;"/>
    </svg>
```

For a ready made chessboard there is my https://chessmeister.github.io/ WebComponent.

If you only want the chess pieces, open https://chessmeister.github.io/elements.chessmeister.js and copy the **SVG_chesspiece** function .. there is an UNlicense on it.. you are free to do what you want.